# web browser shows brighter image than in image preview(also photoshop) (CMYK/RGB)

Tags: javascript, image, browser

I made online image editor using fabricjs and I have serious problem that image quality and color is different.

image preview(MAC os)

[image]

fabricjs image object(brighter and zigzag)

[image]

How it can be fixed?

Image showing code

```
fabric.util.loadImage(url, function(image) {
    if (!image) return;
    var object = new fabric.Image(image);
    canvas.fabric.add(object);
});
```

is there loadImage parameter that load image correctly?(CMYK)

UPDATE: This is CMYK image link.  http://ibb.co/eSogpF

If you download and see this is different in image preview and web browser.

Comment: Please add the code on how you export this image and when it appears bad. Also what fabric.js version are you using? ( start a stackoverflow snippet would be better)

Comment: Please download  http://ibb.co/eSogpF in mac sierra and open it using photoshop or image preview

Comment: Only Safari seems able to load CMYK profile. I even tried with [FF flags](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Gfx.color_management.enabled),  but to no avail. But anyway, this is not related to fabricjs. Can't you convert your images to sRGB?

Comment: There are lots of pictures with CMYK mode and I cant ask customers to convert CMYK to RGB

Comment: There is no color management API in browsers today (some has built-in basic support + system in some cases). You could install [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) at server and convert via that. You would anyway want sRGB it you intend to edit the image content in the browser (the canvas, which fabricjs is based on, can only handle RGB colors + alpha channel).